# Geopandas unary_union keeping lowest value

Tags: python, geopandas

[image]I have a shapefile with 850,000 records. What I am trying to do is merge all adjacent polygons and keep the lowest value for the group.

so for example my polygon is land_plots and has a crop_yield field which is numeric. Some of my land plots touch and some do not.

So i am

```
import geopandas as gpd
shp = '/content/drive/land_plots.shp'
df = gpd.read_file(shp)
# merge adjacent polygons
mergedPolys = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=list(df.unary_union))
```

so here i end up with around 50,000 records and i need to assign the lowest crop yield from each plot.

in the image they are squares but in reality they are irregular shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the code above is what i believe will work, albeit very slow and probably not the most efficient.

```
mergedPolys['PolygonGroupID'] = mergedpolys.index
points = df.copy()
points['geometry'] =points['geometry'].centroid
pointInPoly = gpd.sjoin(mergedPolys, points, op='contains')
poly_agg = pointInPoly.dissolve(by='polygonGroupID', aggfunc = 'min')
```

Maybe someone has a better way?